# Assistance with work - Upload file (gui), process file, parse file - Over my head

Tags: java

This is my first post and while I wish it could be something helpful instead I am required to ask for help. I have been given a projcet for work which is a bit out of my depth. The project requires me to create:

Note that any data used in the question or answers has been sanitized and replaced with dummy sample data.

1. A GUI where a user can browse for an input a file. (This part is done).
2. A process to take the file (will be .ach or NACHA) and then select lines from that file and write them to a new file based on some conditions. (Some lines will be written once, some more than once).

I have no real idea how to proceed. I know that I need to read line by line and somehow check for conditions to be met, then loop and check again. I will first share my code so far, then an example of the type of file I need to process.

```
package nacha_batch_project;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;



public class NACHAFileReader {


  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser Popup");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

    final JLabel directoryLabel = new JLabel(" ");
    directoryLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 36));
    contentPane.add(directoryLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    final JLabel filenameLabel = new JLabel(" ");
    filenameLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 36));
    contentPane.add(filenameLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
    fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
    contentPane.add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
            .getSource();
        String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
          File selectedFile = theFileChooser.getSelectedFile(); 
          //Scanner with loop to read lines
          
          try{
              
              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(selectedFile);
              
              int count=0;
              
              while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                  
                  String line = scanner.nextLine();
                  count++;
                  System.out.println(line);
                  
                  
                  
              }
            System.out.println("Total Line Count: "+count);
              scanner.close();
          }
          catch (FileNotFoundException e){
              
              
              e.printStackTrace();
              
          }
          
        } else if (command.equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
          directoryLabel.setText(" ");
          filenameLabel.setText(" ");
        }
      }
    };
    fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);         
    
        
    }
  
}
```

An example of a file that I would input would look much like this.

```
101 0910000438386C094101WELLS Random BANK, NA   EMMAM                  WFD     
5225Bank Bank AM               5222222222222222 PIT   150810150810   
62709100038858322223883      0000222222222WW1         Guy1  Name1
62792932838828392939293      3822222222222223         Guy2  Name2   
822500000100091000010000000001050000000000005133133497                         
9000001000001000000010009100001000000000105000000000000                                      99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
(More of these lines of 9999)
```

So I would need to pull that 500 number and attach the first 627 number as one batch, then for the next batch pull the 500 number again and the second 627 number an so on.

Anyone have any advice on how I could achieve this or at least the direction to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with .ach files, so I'm going off of this resource: [AAP201 - ACH File Formatting](https://www.nacha.org/system/files/resources/AAP201%20-%20ACH%20File%20Formatting.pdf#page=11)

A record is apparently 94 characters with standard indexes marking sections of data. There are a variety of sections however where the indexes mean different things. This means you probably have to create conditions to not only identify sections or blocks but also handle them differently depending on the content inside. I'll show two sections I came across, [page 11](https://www.nacha.org/system/files/resources/AAP201%20-%20ACH%20File%20Formatting.pdf#page=11) and [page 19](https://www.nacha.org/system/files/resources/AAP201%20-%20ACH%20File%20Formatting.pdf#page=19), and one snippet of code.

## File Header Records

[image]

If your task is simply to break each line into its parts, then it appears you can substring the necessary parts from your line string:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String recordType =                 line.substring(0,1);
String priorityCode =               line.substring(1,2);
String immediateDestination =       line.substring(3,12);
String immediateOrigin =            line.substring(13,22);
String fileCreationDate =           line.substring(23,28);
String fileCreationTime =           line.substring(29,32);
String fileIdModifier =             line.substring(33,34);
String recordSize =                 line.substring(34,36);
String blockingFactor =             line.substring(37,38);
String formatCode =                 line.substring(39,40);
String immediateDestinationNumber = line.substring(40,62);
String immediateOriginName =        line.substring(63,85);
String referenceCodeO =             line.substring(86,93);
```

I'll leave data type parsing up to you - you know, in case you need integers rather than strings or something.

There are some important "block" rules on [page 4](https://www.nacha.org/system/files/resources/AAP201%20-%20ACH%20File%20Formatting.pdf#page=4) of the above reference. You'll have to account for these too probably:

An ACH file must be "BLOCKED"
- Contain enough ACH records to form a complete "block" (10 records = 1 block = 940 character)
- All records within each ACH file are counted
      * file header, batch header, entry detail, addenda, batch control and file control
 – If total number of records do not equal a complete block, "9 filler records" must be added to complete the block
      * 94 characters of 9's = One "9 filler record"

```
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

## Company Batch Header

[image]

Your problem is growing in size and complexity as you need to set conditions to handle a variety of headers. It's really beyond the scope of my ability where I sit. It seems you've got to get familiar with their documentation and the ACH blocks you'll be working with.

Comment: Thanks for that I'm going to use the header and it certainly was informative.